# Quick way to ommit a part of code in PHP while debugging without using comments

Tags: php, tags, comments

What is the way to quickly ommit some code in PHP while debugging or trying different versions of approach without using comments?

E.g. consider this code :

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
```

It would be nice if I can directly tell the PHP to ommit the middle if without commenting it out.

E.g. with using some kind of marker/tag like in a book.

Is there something like that? Commenting the code back and forth while trying to find the right approach to my problem seems cumbersome.

Comment: Why can't you uncomment it?

Comment: Well, I am using goto while prototyping, seems to be quicker while finding the right approach instead of commenting and uncommenting. I just basically define `goto end;` where is the interruption and then the end point like `end:` It's the fastest way while prototyping, unless somebody has a better way of doing this. Waiting for your ideas. I hope that PHP has some hidden prototyping gem strategies I am not aware of ;D

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any goto's in it. It really helps if the code you post is as close to the real code as possible. You're real problem is you're using goto's. :-(

Comment: @RichardAtHome goto has nothing to do with my question at all. It's one of the things I am using. I am interested in more sophisticated techniques and it seems that real time branching - very young concept in IDEs - only in alpha in some IDEs - is the only way to speed up prototyping in programming. Again, I am talking about prototyping not versioning etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try a take on 'feature flags', just toggle them between true and false to 'turn on' the relevant sections of code that you want to run. Consider this:

```
$method1 = true;
$method2 = false;
$method3 = false;

if ($method1 && ($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if ($method2 && socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if ($method3 && socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's too much writing while finding the right way to approach things and too much editing after finding the right way etc. For now, I think goto is the fastest way while prototyping. I define the breakpoint/jumppoint by `goto end;` and then `end:` as teh endpoint. But maybe there is something even faster? Any idea?

Comment: In this case you could use the strategy pattern. You create an instance of the correct strategy and execute that. You can wrap up the instancing of the strategy in a Strategy Pattern Factory (object or method) to keep your code sensible.